# Gradle compatibility between Android Studio 4.0.1 and IntelliJ 2020.2 IDE

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Just an observation that AS4.0.1 no longer clobbers IntelliJ (2020.2) initiated project settings any more, and merely complains of 'unsupported Modules' being detected(Note *).

Is this the beginning of Détente with peaceful co-existence (I wouldn't want to be unhappily surprised in future)?

Just to give specific context, here is what I refer to: (both reject the last configuration - a failed hack) and utilise their preferred first or second one respectively: This is a GOOD thing)

From IDEA 2020.2:
Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: CalibSense.app.
Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.
The IDE modules below were removed by the Gradle project reload:

```
        app
        
You can open DIALOG to select the ones you need to restore.
DIALOG LIST:
    Android App: 
        [x]app
        [v]Badroid.CalibSense.app (level: WORKSPACE)
        [x]CalibSense.app (level: WORKSPACE)
```

From AndroidStudio 4.0.1(somewhere between IDEA 2019.2 and 2019.3):

Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: CalibSense.app.
Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

```
DIALOG LIST:
    Android App: 
        [v]app
        [x]Badroid.CalibSense.app (level: WORKSPACE)
        [x]CalibSense.app (level: WORKSPACE)
```

Suggested Update AS 4.1 (including - All improvements from IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4)

Note *: It turns out they both complain of an illegal configuration, not of each others working configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.
The problem is in a different version of the IntelliJ Platform. Android Studio and IntelliJ Idea is developing separately because it's different products of different companies.
Google adopts the IntelliJ Platform in Android Studio - so we can think about it as about hacked IDEA.
So usually backward compatibility exists - it means that I can open in a new version of IntelliJ IDEA my older projects, but not vice versa.
So if look at AS 4.0 release notes we can mention that it is based on IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#4.0-idea-2019-3-3). But your try to open a project of newer version IntelliJ Platform (2020.2). So it fails because your try to open a newer project version (2020.2) by old IDEA (2019.3.3)
But you can without issues open a project of AS 4.0 with IDEA 2020.2 - it will simply convert older project layout to new.

Comment: I would have thought Gradle could prevent or avoid this persistent version skew at upstream? There was plenty breakage from them on the AS side about two years ago?

Comment: Gradle is a build system. It's independent of IDE. You may build your project from the command line without issues.
IDEA generates different work staff - indexes, databases, etc. It's locate in .idea folder . So when you open project with IDE, if this folder exist, it try to parse this files.
The lag between AS and IDEA exists all time.

Comment: I suppose Gradle is independent of the IDE, but once it gets embedded into it (especially where buildtools, dependencies and other peripheral configuration parameters are kept) then it becomes dependent. Is it not possible for Gradle to mandate _all_ downstream integrators to follow a recommended way of merging into their respective IDEs, and then further down stream, say IntelliJ recommending how AS to conform to its way of merging, perhaps based on semantics of Project, Module, App etc? (Sorry, this is just a theoretical question).

Comment: I added a bit more detail to the question to show what I meant by co-existence, which is a NICE thing. AS prefers the first project config, IDEA the second. They both reject the 3rd which I think is my failed hack from some years back. I've become more comfortable with IDE-driven updates than with the Gradle-only ones so I'll do this one (AS4.0.1=>4.1) which should sustain peaceful co-existence.

Comment: The AS cannot update 4.0.1 to 4.1 because "plugin incompatible with the new build found: Firebase Services", which is an alright SAFE thing to avoid for me.

Comment: UPDATE: AS 4.0.1 still will not update to 4.1.1 for same reason. Updater may be detecting installed IDEA tool chain instead of the AS one.